# Why do I see the contents of binary files?

Tags: c++

Why I can open and view binary files . odd appearance that is impossible ?
http://codepad.org/OwX99H0p

1. Enter a string str -> char arr1[] -> FILEOUT.DAT
2. FILEOUT.DAT -> char arr2[] -> Printed screens

The code in question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void NhapMang(char *&arr, string str , int &n)
{
    n = str.length();
    arr = new char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = str[i];
    }
}

void XuatMang(char *arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n;i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
}

void GhiFile(ofstream &FileOut, char *arr, int n)
{
    FileOut.open("OUTPUT.DAT", ios::out | ios::binary);

    FileOut.write(arr, n*sizeof(char));

    FileOut.close();
}

void DocFile(ifstream &FileInt, char *&arr, int n)
{
    FileInt.open("OUTPUT.DAT", ios::in | ios::binary);

    arr = new char[n];
    FileInt.read(arr, n*sizeof(char));

    FileInt.close();
}

int main()
{
    char *arr1;
    int n1;

    fflush(stdin);
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    NhapMang(arr1, str,n1);

    ofstream FileOut;
    GhiFile(FileOut, arr1, n1);

    char *arr2;
    int n2 = n1;

    ifstream FileInt;
    DocFile(FileInt, arr2, n2);
    XuatMang(arr2, n2);

    delete[] arr1;
    delete[] arr2;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because everything is just bytes (or `char[]`) to C++. `std::ios::binary` just more or less means *read the file raw, don't do any translations that are only meaningful for text files* (the standard actually leaves the meaning undefined).

Comment: What _else_ did you expect? You opened a binary file and chose to `cout` each byte. What else would happen in this situation?

Comment: odd appearance of the file content is binary computer code . we will be unable to apply the content to defend in binary files . But here I could open that view it as normal ? . Does my program right or wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You're ultimately storing data in a file. What this data represents is up to you, keep in mind, it's all '1's and '0's in the end. When you open the file you've created with a text editor, it will try to interpret this data as text which doesn't give a readable result.

Imagine storing a liquid in a bottle. If you don't label it, no one knows what it is. If you then pour this liquid in your car, it will try to use this as gasoline and potentially wreck your engine. Computers, fortunately, are much more forgiving.

Most files store information about how the data can be interpreted in their headers so programs can check if the file type is supported or not. So trying to open this file in a media player for example is most likely telling you that this format is not supported instead of trying to interpret the data as a media.